# Euler's theorem application last two digits of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to find the last two decimal digits of the decimal number $9^{201}$. These can be thought as the remainder leaved out by dividing by 100. I've applied Euler's theorem and since 100 is coprime with 9 and since $\phi(100) = 40$ I've got $9^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$.

Now since

$$9^{201} = 9^{(40 \cdot 5 + 1)} = (9^{40})^5 \cdot 9 \equiv 1^5 \cdot 9 \pmod{100} \equiv 1 \cdot 9 = 9 \pmod{100}$$

This means that $9^{201}$ and $9$ leave out the same remainder when divided by $100$ so I can conclude the last digit is $9$.

But I don't find a rigorous way to find out the penultimate digit. I've was mentioned different heuristic methods but I don't find them appropriate. In this case it should be $0$, but I'm not sure why. If instead of $9$ there were a two digit number like $78$ it would be clear that the two last digits are $78$.

Comment: You're finished.  You have correctly shown that $9^{201}\equiv 9\pmod {100}$ so the last two digits are $09$.

Comment: Maybe you can find answer to your question by searching for "last two digits" here. This gives about 1700 results.

Comment: What should be not rigorous in this calculation ? If the base is not coprime to $100$ , the problem is slightly more difficult.

Comment: For future: use `\pmod{100}`, not `\quad mod \, 100`.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the answer. Consider a simpler example: The last two digits of 709 are "09" because $709 \equiv 9 \pmod{100}$. "mod 100" always* gives the last two digits (even if we don't always write them both).

* In base 10, before anyone gets pedantic.